# How to manipulate user's form entry before submitting in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ransack

I need to manipulate the user's entry before submitting it for search. I'm using the ransack gem for Rails. I want to search through three columns: street address, city, and zip code. Street address and city are working fine. But since zip is an integer, I'm having a conflict between the string entry and the integers in the database. Without creating a new field, is there some way I can use "to_f" or something similar to convert the user's entry before submitting it? Here's my search form.

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :address_or_city_cont, :placeholder => 'Enter Street Address OR City' %>
  <%= f.submit "Search Homes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The form input will always come in as a string, but what you can do is manipulate the data on the server side to convert the input to an integer using `.to_i` where building up the search query.

Comment: Right, manipulating it on the server side is exactly what I want to do. I'm just new to Rails and don't know specifically how to go about it. Could you give a simple example of what that would look like in code? Thanks for your help Keith.

Comment: I'm not the most familiar with ransack so some of this might not work. I noticed the field in your form says `address_or_city_cont`. Can that be changed to `address_or_city_or_zip_code_cont`? If not, I would inject the search value into params on the server side like `params[:search][:zip_code] = <search value>`. The hash might have to be formatted different from this based on how ransack expects things.